# Core Data inverse relationship and deleting unused objects

Tags: core-data, cascading-deletes, inverse

I have a Core Data model similar to this:

[image]

When a *Webgallery* or *Article* object gets saved, it may use one or many pictures. They can use the same photographical subject but maybe in different sizes. I don't save pictures that don't get used in either a *WebGallery* or an *Article*.

*Picture*'s relationships *instance* and *social* are set to cascade, so when the *Picture* object gets deleted, the corresponding *PictureInstance* and *Social* objects get deleted too.

1) Is there any way to know when a picture doesn't get used anymore, neither by *WebGallery* nor by *Article* so it can be deleted?

2) Is it a problem that the relationships *previewPicture* and *teaserPicture* don't have an inverse?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what reason don't you have an inverse?

Comment: Because there might be 10 other entities similar to WebGallery or Article but most of the time only one inverse wouldn't be nulled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an inverse for the relationship. With the inverse, the question becomes trivial. When a simple cascade rule will delete them from WebGallery and Article. (or perhaps you just want to nullify).

> You should typically model relationships in both directions, and specify the inverse relationships appropriately. Core Data uses this information to ensure the consistency of the object graph if a change is made (see “Manipulating Relationships and Object Graph Integrity”). For a discussion of some of the reasons why you might want to not model a relationship in both directions, and some of the problems that might arise if you don’t, see “Unidirectional Relationships.”

(Core Data Programming Guide)

You can simply check if a picture is used whenever you delete it from a gallery or article:

```
[gallery removePictureObject:pictureToRemove];
if (pictureToRemove.galleries.count == 0 && pictureToRemove.articles.count == 0) {
    [managedObjectContext deleteObject:pictureToRemove];
}
```

Comment: So how would you set the delete rule? Can I have unused pictures deleted automatically?

Comment: You could check whenever you delete a picture from a web gallery or article. See my edit.